# Is there a way to see what command are run on your computer?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, shell, command-line

I was wondering how I could see the actions that are done on my computer but on my cmd prompt.

For example: Imagine I click on the shortcut Google Chrome on my desktop, then this will appear on my cmd prompt (or anywhere else):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe
```

modulo the - and -- arguments but that was just for the example.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really a StackOverflow question - more suitable for SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) (also called ProcMon), filtered on ProcessCreate. It'll list every process that gets created, along with the arguments and lots of other useful information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my goal is to then kind of copy paste what I got and I don't know if it is possible with ProcMon. I'm sorry if my message is not so appropriate in this forum.

Comment: You can export the output from ProcMon in a variety of formats, and then open up the results in a text editor. You can also copy any field of the ProcMon display quite easily.

Comment: I can see this but there are like 1000 of chrome.exe line how can I choose which one is the one to use to obtain C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe if I keep the same example?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you need to filter on ProcessCreate. See e.g. https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/procmon-track-process-creation-exit-time/ for a sample filter.